# ComboBox.SelectedItem in DataGridTemplateColumn doesn't bind to its own DataGridRow

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, combobox

After 1.5 days of headscratching, coffee-consuming efforts, I finally give in and call out for your wise advice :).

I found quite a few posts about `ComboBox DataBinding` inside a `DataGrid TemplateColumn`, but none of them seemed to help me.

This is my problem:

I have a `ViewSource` with objects containing information about Excel columns:
column name, column index and an object with database column info.

My second `ViewSource` is a list of those objects with database column info.

My goal was to load all `Excel` columns in a `WPF DataGrid` and have a `ComboBox` in each row that lists all database columns.

This works fine when I use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, but I don't like that a user has to click 3 times to open the ComboBox. And it isn't very obvious visually that you need to click it anyway. (ok perhaps I can style it).

So I put a normal `WPF ComboBox` in a `DataGridTemplateColumn` but ALL ComboBoxes have SelectedItem bound to the DataGrid.SelectedItem, instead of the actual row they belong to. And whatever I try, I can't get this to behave! :)

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="ColumnMappings" DataContext="{StaticResource ColumnMappingsViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,146,10,40" Background="{DynamicResource ControlContainerBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlContainerBorderBrush}" AlternationCount="2" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" RowBackground="{DynamicResource RowBackGroundBrush}" AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource RowAlternatingBackGroundBrush}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ColumnName}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Excel Kolom" Width="5*"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EntityPropertiesViewSource}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EntityProperty}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" Header="Database Kolom" Width="5*"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Database Kolom" Width="5*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EntityPropertiesViewSource}}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding EntityProperty}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Remove the `DataContext` on your combobox. `EntityProperty` resides in your current row DataContext instead of DataGrid's DataContex. Isn't it?

Comment: That was my first try (and it does work with checkboxes). But when I remove the DataContext here, all boxes still get the same value when I change one of them, and now the actual row isn't even updated (the datagridcomboboxcolumn doesn't change). :(

Comment: In other posts I've read that the ComboBox ItemSource "overwrites" the DataContext. My best guess is that I need to specify the correct DataContext (the one of the row), but I don't know where to point it... `AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}` didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it to work now. The trick was to avoid using a seperate DataContext for the ItemSource...

```
     <DataGrid x:Name="ColumnMappings" DataContext="{StaticResource ColumnMappingsViewSource}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,146,10,40" Background="{DynamicResource ControlContainerBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ControlContainerBorderBrush}" AlternationCount="2" HeadersVisibility="Column" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" RowBackground="{DynamicResource RowBackGroundBrush}" AlternatingRowBackground="{DynamicResource RowAlternatingBackGroundBrush}" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ColumnName}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Excel Kolom" Width="5*"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EntityPropertiesViewSource}}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding EntityProperty}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" Header="Database Kolom" Width="5*"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Database Kolom" Width="5*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EntityProperties}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" 
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding EntityProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Only downside is that each of my ColumMapping objects need to have a copy of the complete list of the EntityProperties:

```
public class ColumnMapping
{
    public ColumnMapping(string columnName, int columnIndex, EntityProperty entityProperty, List<EntityProperty> entityProperties)
    {
        ColumnName = columnName;
        ColumnIndex = columnIndex;
        EntityProperty = entityProperty;
        EntityProperties = entityProperties;
    }

    public string ColumnName { get; private set; }
    public int ColumnIndex { get; private set; }
    public EntityProperty EntityProperty { get; set; }
    public List<EntityProperty> EntityProperties { get; private set; }
}

public class EntityProperty
{
    public EntityProperty(string displayName, string name)
    {
        DisplayName = displayName;
        Name = name;
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
}
```

If anyone might know a better (cleaner) solution, let me know :)